# Using different Server IPs in Javascript GET/POST requests?

Tags: javascript, get, header, request

After searching for a while and didn't find what I was hoping for I'm really asking myself if it's possible to send GET/POST requests with 2 different ips, if the server/vps has 2 different IP addresses assigned?

The GET requests looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "http://url",
    dataType: "json",
    success: processData,
    error: function() {
        somefunctio();
    }
    });
```

My questions are:
Is it possible to access the header of that GET request that should be sent and if so, what do I need to change to change the IP address in that request?

Or would I need to migrate to another language, such as c++ or node to make that happen?

Comment: you can use the IP you want to access instead of the URL in the request.

Comment: I'm talking about my OWN ip, not the target ip

Comment: From your question it's not very clear what you are implementing, the server or the client. If it's the client you can't change it. If it's the server you might be able to configure the http server to respond to one of the ips but not the other.